# Sort List of Arrays by String Date Value

Tags: javascript

```
data = [["Apples", 606.8, "pos151.5", "12-11-19"],
["Apples", 608.8, "pos213.9", "12-11-19"],
["Apples", 610.5, "pos271.6", "12-11-19"],
["Apples", 612.5, "pos325", "12-11-19"],
["Apples", 609.4, "pos521.7", "12-11-19"],
["Apples", 611.1, "pos622.8", "12-11-19"],
["Bananas", 626.1, "pos175", "02-20-20"],
["Bananas", 626.1, "pos234.2", "02-20-20"],
["Bananas", 630, "pos321", "02-20-20"],
["Bananas", 620.6, "pos97", "02-20-20"],
["Pears", 616.5, "pos150.9", "10-17-19"],
["Pears", 616.6, "pos17.2", "10-17-19"],
["Pears", 615.4, "pos300.9", "10-17-19"],
["Pears", 614, "pos446.9", "10-17-19"],
["Oranges", 616.1, "pos127.69", "10-21-19"],
["Oranges", 616.1, "pos177.49", "10-21-19"],
["Oranges", 616.1, "pos233.69", "10-21-19"],
["Oranges", 616.5, "pos383.73", "10-21-19"],
["Oranges", 616.3, "pos546.93", "10-21-19"],
["Oranges", 615.2, "pos637.99", "10-21-19"]]
```

How would I sort this list of arrays in ascending date order by the 4th value in each array (date string)?

I assume it is something like this, but I am not sure how to call the 4th value in the array without a field name/key:

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When no keys are set for arrays, they are simply accessed via a zero based numerical index. So to access the 4th item, you would use `data[3]`. So given your sort example,

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return new Date(a[3]).getTime() - new Date(b[3]).getTime()
});
```